# Does HTTP/1.1 server know if client is not there anymore?

Tags: http, tcp

Client connects to server and sends request with `keep-alive` header. Server response also contains `keep-alive` header.

Now client loses power. Is there any mechanism (like ping) in TCP or HTTP stack, which tells server, that client is not there (other than timeout)?

Answer (score 0):

> Now client loses power. Is there any mechanism (like ping) in TCP or HTTP stack, which tells server, that client is not there (other than timeout)?

There is [TCP keep alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP_keepalive) which is specifically designed to detect lost connectivity.